# Input mask for date or year

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, input-mask, jquery-inputmask

I need a special input mask in JS/jquery for this special case:

- normal date input mask which also allows dates like "00.00.1998" or "12.12.0000" or "12.12.9999" (this part I already have using this plugin: http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/)
- beside the normal date input it should also be possible to enter year only (it is enough to recognize if the entered input has a length of 4), in that case the input of e.g. "1998" should result in "00.00.1998"
- The last requirement is: if I go to the first position in the input field and start to type the input should overwrite the existing date char by char, i.e. not shift the chars to the right.

It is not necessary to check for correct dates, this will be done by the backend the input is sent to, so it is ok to check for numeric characters only.

I already looked into this plugin: https://github.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask but was not able to make it work as described (maybe my JS/jquery knowledge is too little)

Hope you have some hints or you know a library I could use to achieve the result.

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: Here I used the OR operator of RobinHerbots jquery: but I need to enter a separator (".") here to switch from year input to date: https://jsfiddle.net/sdy342wd/5/

Comment: Here a solution which is sufficient for us, maybe someone can reuse it: https://jsfiddle.net/mzozmr6p/5/